# Best data feed products for fundamentals data

Tags: data, historical-data, fundamentals

I'm curious if there is any consensus 'leader' in terms of vendors selling (via data feed) fundamental data on global, publicly traded equities. Am curious for any thoughts on Worldscope Fundamentals (by LSEG/Refinitiv) and S&P Premium Financials (by S&P Global).

Comment: This is related but I don't feel answers it exactly, seems more like an outline of all the providers out there. There is mention of S&P's Compustat dataset as being regarded as the best, but where that differs from my question is Compustat's coverage is ~strictly North American securities and I'm interested in global fundamentals data (which is what S&P's Premium Financials offers as an example). Thank you though!

Comment: Very generally, Compustat has a North America version, which is somewhat better than the same equities in Worldscope, and a global version, which is not as good as Worldscope for non-US names. But "good" depends on which fields you need.